# Custom Node does not render edge to the connector properly

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to create a custom node component with multiple source and target handles.
When connected, edges connect to the middle of the node not on the relevant handler.
I have tried adding separate sourceHandler and Targethandler properties when defining the elements.
I want to the edge arrows to connect to the edge of the handlers not on the middle of the node.

[Image of How the arrow head renders to the middle not the edge of the handler](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XPjrB.png)

Handler Definition

```
   <Handle
         type="target"
         position="left"
         id="topicLeft1"
         style={{
             borderRadius: 50,
             width: "1rem",
             height: "1rem",
             background: "var(--Brand_Color_1)",
             top: "60%",
              }}
     />
```

other handlers are similar to this but set to a different ID and position with either source or target type accordingly

Element

```
generated_elements.push({
                    id: `${link.source}-${link.target}`,
                    source: link.source,
                    target: link.target,
                    type: 'buttonedge',
                    sourceHandle : current_relationshipProperties.sourceHandle,
                    targetHandle : current_relationshipProperties.targetHandle,
                    animated : isAnimated,
                    style : {
                        stroke : edgeColor
                    },
                    arrowHeadType : "arrowclosed"
                })
```